# Use of sed to search two patterns and replace with one

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file that contains either one of the following :

&messages 
 oR

messages

Both start begining of the line. 
How can i search in the file if it contains either #messages or messages and then replace it with Messages

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/#?messages/Messages/g'
```

? denotes 0 or 1 element

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r -e 's/^[#]?messages/Messages/' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Note the anchoring to the beginning of the line for the pattern; this won't get confused on input like:

```
$messages $messages more$messages
```

Also note the use of the *-r* switch to turn on real regular expressions if you need them.

Comment: `-r` is a GNU extension that activates Extended Regular Expressions (EREs), not "real..." and EREs are not needed in this case, just Basic REs which is what all seds support by default. Also there's no need to make `#` into a character list as it's not an RE meta-character.